# Wordpress - Don't show Advanced custom field meta in default Custom Fields dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the plugin [**ACF**](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) which uses the  [wordpress meta data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) Or something similar to save the field name/content.

The problem I have is, I use the default wordpress Custom Fields for a few things, but once you've added a few fields through ACF it fills the list with generated content.

[image]

Which makes it hard for the client to find the fields that are used e.g tagline.

Is there anyway to filter what is output here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an underscore as a first character of your custom field name for ACF. Like `_performances` or `_mycustomfield` This would make the custom field hidden into the native custom field form in each post. For reference read it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta#Hidden_Custom_Fields).

Comment: Brilliant solution. Couldn't of been simpler. Only had to put _ on one field as well as it was a repeater. Thanks a lot.